# Image UniformFill centered

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I have a little problem, I have a group item which I want to give a background image which it should scale keeping it's correct dimensions but by default it shows the image from the top left, I want the image to be centered.

[image]

this is my code

```
 <Grid>
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="180" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="300" />
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <Border BorderThickness="2" Width="180" Height="101" Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Top">
         <Image Source="{Binding Imageurl} Width="180" Height="101" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Stretch="UniformToFill"></Image>
     </Border>
     <TextBlock Text="Example1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
     <TextBlock Text="Example2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove *Width* and *Height* of your *Image* - you want it to fill the container so it should use container's properties. Also if you want it to be centered then you need to define *VerticalAlignment* (and maybe horizontal one). I think what you are looking for is:

```xml
 <Border BorderThickness="2" Width="180" Height="101" Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Top">
     <Image Source="{Binding Imageurl}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
 </Border>
```

You also don't need `Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"` in `Image` - those properties won't have effect - image's container is *Border* (which is inside *Grid*) and there you should define *Column*/*RowSpan*.

Comment: Is there a specific reason that this doesn't longer work on UWP?

Comment: In my case the Source is not setted through an URL, but through a BitmapImage that is created from a byte array. So the image stays "left" alignated instead of being centered...

Comment: is it prefereable to create a new thread or to describe my case here?

Comment: @Gold.strike Definitely the new thread, with your code, and if posible images of current and desired view.

Comment: Sorry for my comments, finally it works fine. The problem was coming from the export of the original image with the shapes added by the user. the `encoder.SetPixelData()` that is used for doing this didn't keep the ratio ot image, which misled me...

Comment: @Gold.strike No problem at all.